# Combine multiple mysql queries to get result as a single row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table : question

```
id   | name
-----+-----
 2   | name 1
 3   | name 2 
 4   | name 3
 5   | name 4
 10  | name 5 
 20  | name 6
 21  | name 7
```

I have an id say 5, I need to get the previous and next rows, so if id is 5 I need to get 4, 5 and 10

Now I am using these queries

```
select * from question where id = (select max(id) from question where id < 5);
select * from question where id = (select min(id) from question where id > 5);
```

What I am looking is for a single query (if its possible). Some thing like

```
SELECT xx AS prevId, id, yy AS nextId FROM questions WHERE .......
```

If there is not previous id or next id it should be 0 or -1

```
For example
id: 5
Return : 4, 5, 10

id:2
Return : -1, 2, 3

id: 21
Return 20, 21, -1
```

I know how to do this with multiple queries and with some `if` conditions in PHP, but I am looking for a pure mySQL approach if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few examples, someone else can tell which one is more efficient.

**Query 1**

```
Select
  (select id from question where id<5 order by id desc limit 0,1) as prevId,
  id,
  (select id from question where id>5 order by id asc limit 0,1) as nextId
From question
Where id=5;
```

**Query 2**

```
Select
  (select max(id) from question where id<5) as prevId,
  id,
  (select min(id) from question where id>5) as nextId
From question 
Where id=5;
```

Ah, did not see -1 definition, needs some more hacking. Coalesce function takes 1..n arguments and returns first nonnull value.

**Query 3**

```
Select
  Coalesce( (select max(id) from question where id<21), -1) as prevId,
  id,
  Coalesce( (select min(id) from question where id>21), -1) as nextId
From question
Where id=21;
```

Answer (score 0):

For next Record(ID):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ID > $id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;
```

For prev Record(ID):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ID < $id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;
```

Here `$id` is a variable in php which changes according to your desire

Comment: This is similar to what I have in my question. I am looking for something else. Plz check question.